# What's wrong in my regular expression to extract parties of a string in R?

Tags: r, regex, extract

In a data frame there'are string like these:

```
df <- data.frame (Product = c("Chocolate Some_brand 200g 180ml PKG",
                              "Strawberry Grown_locally 380g"))
```

I'm trying to extract only the value of the milliliters to a different variable using these two different ways:

```
df %>% mutate(
   volume = str_extract(Product, '\\d+ml|\\d+ ml')
)
# the return is:
# 180ml
# NA
```

Trying to have the sabe return but without the ml string I'm trying something like this:

```
df %>% mutate(
   volume = str_extract(NombreProducto, '\\d+[^ml]|\\d+[^ ml]')
)
# the return is:
# 180
# 380g
```

What should I do to get these results?

```
# 180
# NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `(?=\s*ml)` lookahead:

```
str_extract(df$Product, '\\d+(?=\\s*ml)')
## => [1] "180" NA
```

Note you may make sure `ml` is matched as a whole word by adding `\b` word boundary after it, and you may support float values by replacing `\d` with `\d*\.?\d+` (or `\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?`):

```
str_extract(df$Product, '\\d*\\.?\\d+(?=\\s*ml\\b)')
```

**Pattern details**

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?=\s*ml)` - a positive lookahead that requires 0 or more whitespaces and then `ml` immediately to the right of the current location, but does not add the matched text to the overall match value since lookahead patterns are non-consuming.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! It works just fine!!! I'm struggling a lot with regular expressions and your explanation was really clear.

Comment: @DiegodeLima If you are still having problems with this just drop a comment. I added some more options just in case your data is not homogenous, like `\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?` to match float numbers with commas or dots as decimal separators.

Comment: Wiktor, that's OK. I noticed your updates, and the options will be useful in my code too.